# Angular - How can i raplace whole caracter in entire JSON?

Tags: json, angular, angular6

I've just found a way to pass ampersand through my URL but at the moment I can replace only my first character.

My json is like this:

```
{
  "post_ID": 0,
  "post_date": "2018-10-12",
  "post_content": "Post content test",
  "post_image": "example.png",
  "article_tittle": "Article tittle test",
  "article_content": "<p>first &amp;</p><p>second &amp;</p>",
  "post_category": "INF"
}
```

And this is my code in angular

```
addPost(post: Post) {
  let json = JSON.stringify(post);
  let params = 'json=' + json.replace('&', '%26');
  //let params = 'json='+json;
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  });

  return this._http.post(this.url + 'posts', params, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
}
```

The ('&','%26'); will replace my first & but not the second &, I must create a second array in order to process whole text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression like this

```
let params = 'json='+json.replace(new RegExp('&', 'g'), '%26');
```

Comment: Or the literal: `json.replace(/&/g, '&26')`

Comment: I can confirm that regular expression suggested by firegloves it work perfectly. cheers!

Comment: Or you can use `HttpParams` from `@angular/common/http`, which will encode all of your "faulty" characters ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that simply by using `encodeURI` to create your `queryParams` and `decodeURI` to get the original Object back.

```
const queryParams = {
  "post_ID": 0,
  "post_date": "2018-10-12",
  "post_content": "Post content test",
  "post_image": "example.png",
  "article_tittle": "Article tittle test",
  "article_content": "<p>first &amp;</p><p>second &amp;</p>",
  "post_category": "INF"
};

const encoded = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(queryParams));
...
const decodedObject = JSON.parse(decodeURI(encoded));

...

addPost(post: Post) {

  const params = `json=${encodeURI(JSON.stringify(post))}`;

  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  });

  return this._http.post(this.url + 'posts', params, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
}
```